# How to stop doing nothing on windows Confimation pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this Code in my view. I am doing some Post on Clicking OK button and Cancel Buttong. How to stop Post on clicking Popup window Close button.. that is right upper corner close symbol? here is the sample code which I Implemented can any body help me out how to stop post on Actual closing window?

```
jsfiddle.net/kRqCd/20/
```

Thanks

Comment: When I click the close X in the corner I get your cancel alert. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Exactly, When I click on that I should simply return false; do nothing.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your approach. You've already implemented it by yourself. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kRqCd/22/). Just use `return` to return from the method when you get false value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect the "close" event of the `confirm` box (Note that Firefox don't even put a close option).

Since you're using JQuery you may try to use custom boxes such as :

[JQuery-UI dialogs](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/